# Xcode 8 Objective-C project build error: “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, xcode8

I've just updated my Xcode from 7.31 to 8.

I have an Objective-C project that uses cocoapods.

When I double-clicked on xcworkspace file, it gave me error like:

> “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly."

So I opened Build Settings for the project and pod proj, but I still can't find any options named "Use Legacy Swift Language".

I looked over some articles about this, so I tried to set this flag to NO or YES from undefined. but I can't find this option.

Comment: The cocoapods are written in Swift2.